# The mongo client starts mongod instead

Tags: macos, mongodb, homebrew

When I run mongo on my Ubuntu VM, everything works as expected:

```
fubar@ubuntu:~$ status mongod
mongod start/running, process 31104
fubar@ubuntu:~$ mongo --version
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.0
fubar@ubuntu:~$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.0
connecting to: test
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
For interactive help, type "help".
For more comprehensive documentation, see
        http://docs.mongodb.org/
Questions? Try the support group
        http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user
>
bye
wurstworks@ubuntu:~$ mongo --host localhost
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.0
connecting to: localhost:27017/test
>
```

When I try the same thing on my Mac, using mongod installed from homebrew, it's really weird but mongo has the same effect as runing mongod. That is:

- Typing mongo on the command line starts mongod with the default configuration file
- Typing mongo --help gives the help for mongod
- Typing a legit mongo command line, e.g. mongo --host somehost, that works on my Ubuntu VM gives me an error

The mongo and mongod files in the mongodb bin folder are different, but somehow mongo seems to redirect to mongod! So check this out:

```
fubar@Aerys:~$ ps ax | fgrep -i mongo
57888 s001  S+     0:00.00 fgrep -i mongo
fubar@Aerys:~$ mongo &
[1] 57889
fubar@Aerys:~$ ps ax | fgrep -i mongo
57889 s001  S      0:00.06 mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
57891 s001  S+     0:00.00 fgrep -i mongo
fubar@Aerys:~$ mongo --host localhost
Error parsing command line: unknown option host
try 'mongod --help' for more information
fubar@Aerys:~$ mongo --help > mongo.txt
fubar@Aerys:~$ mongod --help > mongod.txt
fubar@Aerys:~$ diff mongo.txt mongod.txt
fubar@Aerys:~$ ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.6.0_1/bin/mongo /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.6.0_1/bin/mongod
-r-xr-xr-x  1 fubar  admin  14726788 Apr  9 05:43 /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.6.0_1/bin/mongo*
-r-xr-xr-x  1 fubar  admin  26297460 Apr  9 05:43 /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.6.0_1/bin/mongod*
fubar@Aerys:~$ which mongo
/usr/local/bin/mongo
fubar@Aerys:~$ which mongod
/usr/local/bin/mongod
fubar@Aerys:~$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/mongo
lrwxr-xr-x  1 fubar  admin  35 May  4 16:34 /usr/local/bin/mongo@ -> ../Cellar/mongodb/2.6.0_1/bin/mongo
fubar@Aerys:~$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/mongod
lrwxr-xr-x  1 fubar  admin  36 May  4 16:34 /usr/local/bin/mongod@ -> ../Cellar/mongodb/2.6.0_1/bin/mongod
fubar@Aerys:~$
```

Here you can see there's no mongod process running. Then I type mongo and check again and there's the mongod process. You can also see that the mongo --host localhost command fails, which is a totally legit command and works fine on Ubuntu. The mongo and mongod files are different, seem to be getting called at the right time when I type the commands, but in the end mongo is starting mongod and I have no mongo at all.

This is a really big problem for me because I'm actually trying to connect from my Mac mongo client to the Ubuntu mongod server. That is, I don't even want mongod most of the time on my Mac, just mongo to attach to the server!

Is this a bug in the homebrew formula? Or... any thoughts?

Comment: What happens when you execute mongo using the absolute path `/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.6.0_1/bin/mongo`? Also, what's the output of `type mongo`?

Comment: @GergoErdosi That's what I just did and that works fine. It turns out I fumble-fingered an alias definition in my .bash_profile to set the dbpath option and did "alias mongo" instead of "alias mongod". Duh. Thanks for reading, anyway!